# sum of one hundred numbers

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I saw this problem recently. It asks to prove that it is always possible to choose 100 numbers from 200 positive numbers such that their sum will be divisible by 100.

**Attempt to solve:** my first step was to take mod of each number. It helps because then we have to work only with numbers from 1 to 99 (200 in total). Then I have to prove that there is always a sum such that $a_1+a_2+a_3+...a_{100}$  where $a_i \le 99$ is divisible by 100. And here I stuck. A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Some of the individual numbers may be equivalent to $0$ modulo $100$.

Answer (score 11):

This result is a special case of the famous EGZ or [Erdős Ginzburg Ziv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-sum_problem) theorem, which states that any set of $2n-1$ integers, must have some subset of size $n$ whose sum is a multiple of $n$.  Hence we can even throw out one of the 200 numbers; out of any 199 integers, some 100 must sum to a multiple of 100.

You can find some lovely proofs of EGZ on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16721/egz-theorem-erdos-ginzburg-ziv).

Answer (score 5):

The EGZ theorem can be proved through the Cauchy-Davenport theorem:

> If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_{/100\mathbb{Z}}$,
>   $$ |A+B| \geq \min(100,|A|+|B|-1) $$

or the Kneser's theorem:

> If $A,B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_{/100\mathbb{Z}}$ and $C$ is the restricted sumset $\{a+b:(a,b)\in A\times B, a\neq b\}$, then:
>   $$ |C| \geq \min(100,|A|+|B|-3). $$

Both theorems can be proved through the Dirichlet box principle with quite sophisticated proofs, or through the [combinatorial nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset) as shown by Noga Alon in the eighties.

In any case, among $199$ integers there are for sure $100$ integers having sum $\equiv 0\pmod{100}$.

Comment: Wow, I saw this problem in a set of problems for high-school students. Is it really then a superhard olimpiad-level problem? Or somehow there is an easier proof for this particular case?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution in an old russian magazine for high-school students (it is called "Kvant"). The statement is as follows:

> It is always possible to choose from a set of $2n-1$ numbers $n$ numbers such their sum is divisible by n. In other words $\frac{a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n}{n}$ is integer.

Apparently, to prove this statement in general is not very easy as one can see from the answers. But one can prove a lemma which is the key to solve the original problem.

> Consider two sets of numbers with $2a-1$ and $2b-1$ numbers in each. Let these two sets satisfy the previous statement. Then a set with $2ab-1$ numbers will also satisfy the statement.

The proof of this lemma is easy:

> Let's denote the sets with $2a-1$, $2b-1$, $2ab-1$ numbers as $S_a$, $S_b$, $S_{ab}$. As $2ab-1>2b-1$ we can choose $b$ numbers from $S_{ab}$ such that their sum is divisible by $b$. We can remove $b$ numbers from $S_{ab}$ $2a-1$  times because $2ab-1=b(2a-1)+(b-1)$. So now we have $2a-1$ sets of numbers with $b$ numbers in each. But we also know that $S_a$ satisfies the statement (and sum of numbers in the each set is divisible by $b$ ). Now replace the each of $2a-1$ sets by the corresponding sum. So we end up with a set which contains $2a-1$ numbers. Obviously, it is possible to choose $a$ numbers from this set such that their sum is divisible by $ab$.

Now to solve the problem we have to prove the statement for some small prime numbers simply by brute-force and then use the lemma.